# How to custom sort a list with exceptions for first elements then default afterwards

Tags: python-3.x

I have an arbitrary length list of strings I want to sort in alphabetical order unless it is a specific string, then I want those to have "priority" over others and come first.

Example input:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

I want to sort the list such that the values `['c', 'g', 'e']` come first in that order then the rest of the list is sorted alphabetically.

Result:

```
['c', 'g', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'f']
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) I can pass to `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def key_func(elem):
    if elem == "c":
        return chr(0)
    if elem == "g":
        return chr(1)
    if elem == "e":
        return chr(2)
    return elem

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
lst.sort(key=key_func)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'g', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'f']
```

---

Just ensure your list doesn't contain `chr(0)`, `chr(1)` or `chr(2)`

---

If you want different "priority" strings, change `key_func` to this:

```
priority = ['c', 'g', 'e']
def key_func(elem):
    if elem not in priority:
        return elem
    return chr(priority.index(elem))
```